# Removing photos in Google Plus Album Archive

Tags: google-plus, google-maps

The photos I upload to Google Maps are also added to my Google Plus profile's Album Archive, is there a way to delete the photos I have in Google Plus while keeping them available on Google Maps? Basically, every photo I have that is made public via Google, turned into a background image for example, is added to that archive; is there a way to disable this?